# Selenium/ Java not working with IE on Windows

Tags: java, windows, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone please help me with Selenium + Java + IE + Windows code and settings to be done step by step? There are so many conflicting answers over the web and none of those is working (due to lack of my understanding perhaps, I am basically shell and python programmer and shifted to test automation recently). Please help me with code and required settings. Screenshots of settings will be highly appreciated (I am new to windows as a programming environment, I have extensive command line programming experience on *nix systems on shell and python as mentioned earlier).

The problem is that the "Internet Explorer" window is opened, however the test cases are not executed at all and after waiting for some time the Eclipse console shows error.

Thanks,
P Ashwin

Comment: can you please show us the error that you are getting in eclipse console

Comment: You should also add the code you tried to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you download the [IE Driver Server](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/). You'll need 32 bit or 64 bit to match your OSes "bitness."

The executable should be on your path. You can point to it in code as Aramin called out above; however, I prefer to have the executable on the path--doing it in code is just one more configuration mess you have to deal with if you run on different systems.

Note that you'll need to restart any shells/command windows after you add the server's executable to your system environment variables.

After that it's just a matter of firing it up in code and looks like any other WebDriver:

```
WebDriver browser;
public void initialize() {
    browser = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    browser.navigate().to("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com");
}
```

Note: This is from a canned set of demos I use for training. It runs under Cucumber, normally with an @Before tag. I took that out to avoid confusion.

HTH

Comment: The only caveat to this answer is that if you're running IE 10 or 11, you might be [running 32-bit IE content processes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2012/03/23/understanding-enhanced-protected-mode/), even if you're running 64-bit Windows. This means that most often, the 32-bit driver executable is usually the right choice for IE 10 and 11, no matter what bit-ness the OS is.

Comment: Gah. Because it wasn't complex enough already. :p Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

Code :

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
 WebDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver();
 driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com");
```

Along with this you need to enable scripting for IE(Internet Options->Security->Custom level ) as shown in ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJGfl.png)

Hope this will help you..

Comment: Where can I get IEDriverServer.exe for download? Is it different for 32 bit and 64 bit versions of windows? (I am asking this as I do not have much experience with Windows OS.)

Comment: Yes.. it is different for 32bit and 64-bit.